# Searching for information in files in several directories

Tags: linux, unix, search, directory, grep

I need to check several files which are in different locations for a specific information.

So, how to make a script which checks for the argument word through several directories?

The directories are in different locations. For ex.

/home/check1/

/opt/log/

/var/status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do (next to ´find´)
do a

```
for DIR in /home/check1 /opt/log /var/status ; do 
    grep -R searchword $DIR; 
    done
```

Comment: The loop is overkill since `grep` can take multiple directory arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `grep -R` (recursive) option and give `grep` multiple directory arguments.

Comment: The directories are in different locations. For ex.

/home/check1/
/opt/log/
/var/status/

Comment: @Stole: `grep -R pattern /home/check1/ /opt/log/ /var/status/`

Answer (score 1):

At the very simplest, it boils down to

```
find . -name '*.c' | xargs grep word
```

to find a given word in all the .c files in the current directory and below.

`grep -R` may also work for you, but it can be a problem if you don't want to search all files.

Answer (score 0):

Try find http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm using your searchwords and the directories.

Answer (score 0):

The man page of grep should explain what you need. Anyway, if you need to search recursively you can use:

```
grep -R --include=PATTERN "string_to_search" $directory
```

You can also use:

```
--exclude=PATTERN to skip some file
--exclude-dir=PATTERN to skip some directories
```

The other option is use find to get the files and pipe it to grep to search the strings.